# Variable 'varname' used before being initialized in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code in the Xcode playground produces the error in the subject:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test2 {
    var i: Int64
    var j: UUID
}

struct Test {
    @State private var t: Test2
    
    init(_ test: Test2) {
        t = test // Variable 'self.t' used before being initialized
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm not using `t`, I'm assigning it a value.

If I remove `var j: UUID` from the `Test2 struct`, the error goes away.

In my actual code, the Test struct is a view, but that's not necessary to generate the error.

Comment: Where is the Test2 coming from in the initializer?

Comment: @matt From a consumer of the Test struct: `let myTest = Test(Test2(i: 0, j: UUID())`

Comment: But then you need to show that.

Comment: @matt I don't see its relevance. The caller is immaterial. If you enter the code into a playground, you'll get the error.

Comment: Without a value for the `test:` parameter I would never have expected to compile in the first place. You need at least to show code that stands a _chance_ of compiling.

Comment: @matt It compiles fine with the accepted answer. No need for the consumer of the `test struct`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This should work:

```
init(_ test: Test2) {
    _t = State(initialValue: test) // Variable 'self.t' used before being initialized
}
```

@State is a property wrapper, so you need to assign value to the underlying property, thus **_** .